# C++ force specific overload resolution

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm trying to track down memory leaks and thought that it would be good to create a simple device for this, so I made this.

```
struct alloc_t
{ 
};
extern alloc_t g_Alloc;

inline 
void* operator new (size_t size, alloc_t, const char* file, int line)
{
    return _malloc_dbg(size, _NORMAL_BLOCK, file, line);
}
```

I then use a macro to expand to this specific overload like so:

```
#define DEBUG_NEW new (g_Alloc, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

Though, I have to define `g_Alloc` somewhere, I'm thinking there is a better way to make sure that the overload resolution is sade but without using a `struct`. However, I'm note sure to what extent an `enum` or `typedef` would suffice without being confused with `void*` or `int`?

Also, can anyone say from experience wheter the precense of that `g_Alloc` has any impact what so sever or if the compiler just removes it after it's done the overload resolution?

Comment: Already seen `nothrow`? This is the same trick.

Comment: use a template and overload the template signature, it will also be a much more modern approach without using macros .

Comment: @user1797612 could you maybe give an example? I'm not very experienced when it comes to dealing with operator overloads of `new`.

Comment: @ipc Ah, I see but `nothrow` is a type for other specific purpose mixing in that here feels wrong.

Comment: I mean [extern const std::nothrow_t nothrow;](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/nothrow) and the overload [new (nothrow)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)

Comment: @ipc I understand what you mean now...

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @ipc's comment I made this adjustment, it's fundamentally the same but with a const qualifier and pass-by-reference. This is also identical to the trick used by the *new overload by nothrow* that allow you to not get exceptions when allocations fail in C++ (this I did not know about).

```
struct alloc_t
{ 
};
extern const alloc_t g_Alloc;

inline 
void* operator new (size_t size, const alloc_t&, const char* file, int line)
{
    return _malloc_dbg(size, _NORMAL_BLOCK, file, line);
}
```